# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not dequeuing custom UITableViewCell from Nib?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've got this issue for almost a week now and it's really driving me crazy. I've read a lot of topics on Stackoverflow despite any success. Hope anyone could help me out...

**The situation:**

I got a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell which I load from a Nib. I do so in the `ViewDidLoad` of the TableView like this:

```
[self.myTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DividendCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DividendReuseCell"];
```

The custom cell has got a few labels including: `issueName` and `issueType`.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I dequeue the reusable cell like this and assign the labels:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DividendCell *cell;
    cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DividendReuseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    dividend *div = [[[aAgendaItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] agendaItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setDiv:div];

    return cell;
}
```

I suppose I don't need to check `if (!cell)` since I use a custom Nib which will always return a cell.

But the problem is that it looks like the cells are not being dequeued. When I scroll down I can see the labels are being duplicated on top of each other. I have no clue what's going wrong. I did it this way in other classes and had no problems.

Any help is much appreciated! :)

**EDIT:** Screenshot to indicate better what's going wrong:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJTYl.jpg

**EDIT 2** Here's the code for DividendCell
I use this method to assign the labels.

```
-(void)setDiv:(dividend *)div {
    issueName.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[div RelatedIssue] ShortName] capitalizedString]];
    issueType.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[div Description]];

    issueCurrency.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[div Currency]];
    issueKoers.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[super formatDouble:[div BrutValue]]];

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *loc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"nl_NL"];
    [format setLocale:loc];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];

    exDividendDate.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[format stringFromDate:[div ExDividendDate]]];

    NSComparisonResult result = [[div PaymentDate] compare:[NSDate date]];
    exPaymentDate.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[format stringFromDate:[div PaymentDate]]];
    if (result==NSOrderedAscending) {
        [exPaymentDate setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    } else {
        [exPaymentDate setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    [loc release];
}
```

Comment: 1. Please don't post duplicate questions. 2. Please don't edit "Solved" into the title of your questions. 3. Please don't post your solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see your labels, that means your cells are being dequeued. The problem is likely that your cells are malformed with respect how the labels are laid out. If you are NOT using auto layout, then make sure it is not checked in your nib file, and make sure to return the right height forRow by either setting self.myTableview.rowHeight to the proper row height, or using the delegate method. If your labels are appearing on top of one another, this is likely an auto layout issue within your *.xib cell.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. But cells don't appear on top of each other, after scrolling the labels duplicate. See this image of the table: http://imgur.com/DFAqsai.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your cell *.xib file, with all the items on the left expanded out, and the item on the right being the first page that shows whether auto layout is on or off.

Comment: See here: http://imgur.com/54kRCw4.

Comment: Can you try adding constraints to all your cells and seeing if that works?

Comment: what row height did you specify to the tableview? Did you specify an estimatedHeight as well?

Comment: I fixed the issue! See my edited question. Turns out I had to check *Clears Graphic Context* for the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't give proper height of the Cell if use `heightfortherowAtIndexPath` method.

**Edit:**

Did you set **identifer** in you .xib file of cell ?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. My labels overlap each other, see edited question with link to screenshot of the problem included.

Comment: yes I've set my identifier!

Comment: I think you're trying to fit every lables in just 45.0 height only ... that's why your cell seems small in height.

Comment: that's not the issue... All labels fit, except some labels overlap when cell is being reused, see this screenshot: http://imgur.com/0oVGzwW

Comment: Can you put your sample code on github  so, Can I understand what's the problem going on..???

Comment: I fixed the issue! See my edited question. Turns out I had to check _Clears Graphic Context_ for the labels.